# stuck in lxml and xpath in python 3.x

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am parsing an arxml file to extract data from it in python 3.x but I am stuck and can't get myself out the following code. I simply can't understand what I am missing.
With xpath I located the child node from where I want to start extracting data of all its sub-element. I tested the xpath expression (dataExpre3) output in an online tester and it gives me the output as the full xml tree under the node. However, same xpath expression outputs only the list address and not the complete tree under the node in a python code.
Any help on how can I parse child element under node ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE is really appreciated.

```
from lxml import etree
arxmlFile = "D:/7_scripts/ArXmlParser/input/EcucValues.arxml"
tree = etree.parse(arxmlFile)
dataExpre3 = "//*[local-name() = 'SUB-CONTAINERS']/*[local-name() = 'ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE'][1]"
subcontainers = tree.xpath(dataExpre3)
print(subcontainers)
```

The output in python is:
*[<Element {http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE at 0x28f8f26a1c0>]*

The output in xpath tester is complete xml tree of the first child under node ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the list of Element objects that were selected by xpath().

In this case, it's just one Element with the name `{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE`. That's the full name with the namespace uri in Clark notation.

If you want to print the ***serialized*** tree, try (untested):

```py
print(etree.tostring(subcontainers[0]).decode())
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this did show the required tree I was expecting. I need to read more about uri in Clark notation. To be honest I did not know about this.